# CSS - 5 equal Bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, typo3

I know this question has been asked a lot before, but my case is a bit "specific". I'm using a template for TYPO3 and it has a bootstrap content element, where I can tell the template how many columns I need etc. Then it renders the HTML code.

[Here's the website](http://typo3.tabs-spezialreinigung.de/index.php?id=158&no_cache=1).

As you can see I have 2 rows which contain 5 columns per row and I want them to use all the space which is left and be centered. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A grid is not the right choice for elements that need to be spaced evenly and not aligned to the grid lines. You can however easily achieve your goal by using the CSS flexible box model (aka **flexbox**) on the row that contains the items.

The CSS code below sets the container as a flexbox, tells it to space its contents evenly across all the available space and hides the `::after` pseudoelement that is not necessary when using this approach. No changes to the HTML are needed. On browsers that don't support flexbox (under **IE 11**) everything will look the same as before.

```
div#c1131 > .row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div#c1131 > .row::after {
  display: none;
}
```

If browser compatibility is an issue make sure you verify against [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) or similar services.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, the default grid in Bootstrap has 12 parts. So, if you want to use 5 columns in one row that is not really possible.

Either you use a grid column number which can be divided in 3, 4 and 5 columns (60) or you use an own CSS for this special case.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this html in before your given columns in same parent div

```
<div class="col-lg-1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing anything with css in this situations:
Bootstrap has 12 columns: So you can use 2 cols for each box, which means you used 10 cols and two are free. This two cols you could use, one before first box as offset and after last box you should add clear fix.